# fast enumeration over array of integers

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of integers stored in a plist.  I would to load them and do fast enumeration over the array.  Is there a way to do this or does fast enumeration work only for objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fast enumeration do only work with objects in Obj-C.

However, if you stored integer values in a plist, you'll have an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary` instance representing that plist. The `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` works with fast enumeration and will output `NSNumbers` when working with them, not `int`.

That way, you can retrieve your `int` easily with `[anNSNumber intValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

I do undestand OOP is nice but if You have an array of integers and You must scan values very often, consider storing value in a simple C array:


advantages:

1) much less memory footprint
2) blazing speed in searching (for via and index, a REAL index in memory.. will be a register in µp directly...)

disadvantages:
a) you must think in old style C
b) save the number of items
c) you must convert from plist to int arr[..] but is very easy.